# Circular progress bar code swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, progress-bar

I need some help.

I have a circular progress view that I want to display in my app to track the number of workouts completed by the user.

But how do I :

1. Link the button click as an action to count the number of workouts And
2. Link the number of button presses to a new view controller to change the progress bar ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been working on this for a day or so and can't crack it.

Comment: Can you post some part of your code?